# How do I make backbone routing for file://

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to trigger the router on the file:// protocol

Backbone is started using pushstate

```
# Backbone History Start
Backbone.history.start
   pushState : true
   root      : "/"
```

Routes are defined as below

```
"prototyping/scaffolding/contact.html" : "contact"
```

Path example

```
file:///Users/ianwarner/www/prototyping/scaffolding/contact.html
```

I think I am just missing the magic to make this happen - maybe prepend some wildcard to the beginning of the routes?

All help appreciated

Thanks

Ian

Comment: You don't. Set up a web server and use that to prototype your Backbone stuff. File URLs are treated specially by the browser for hopefully obvious reasons.

Comment: And if a webserver is not available on the user's machine.. basically backbone become obsolete.

Comment: Is this issue with the Push State - e.g. change to the # method to get this working.. will give that a little test as it works in my phonegap apps, which I think use the file protocol?

Comment: Thanks for the re-iteration of the OBVIOUS reason, no need to be condescending. I have run some tests and backbone routing will work when not using pushState on the file protocol.